# Load balancing downloads with S3 as a fallback on an Nginx/RoR server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-s3, passenger, load-balancing

I have a `nginx` web server with a `ruby on rails` application running with `phusion passenger`. The RoR application is mostly used to distribute static jsons and zips to `S3`.

As out S3 hosting cost are going up, we would like to use only S3 as a fallback, using the large available bandwidth of our server first.

We don't need to find the optimal solution, in case of doubt falling back to S3 is perfectly acceptable.

What I first thought about was redirecting the user to S3 if I detect more than `N` number of active http connections to the server, but I didn't found a good way to get that information.

How to do this load balancing ?

Comment: Nginx S3 proxy? https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files